# Angular 2 Animation - boolean trigger

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-animations

I have a form with one field and if that field is incorrect I want to shake it using animations

```
<form [formGroup]="subscribeFormGroup">
    <mat-form-field [@error]="isError" class="al-subscribe-form-field">
            <input formControlName="email" matInput type="email">
            <mat-icon class="al-subscribe-icon" svgIcon="mail" (click)="onSubscribeClick()"></mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>


animations: [
    trigger('error', [
        transition('false <=> true', useAnimation(shake)),
    ]),
],

public onSubscribeClick(): void {
        if (this.subscribeFormGroup.invalid) {
            this.isError = true;
        }
    ...
}
```

Now it triggers only at first time when I try to send incorrect data, if I click button the second time etc, the field is not shaking

Comment: Are you setting `isError` back to `false` after the animation is over?

Comment: If the field has valid email, I set isError to false, but I repeatedly click the button with incorrect value and the field should shake until it is invalid

Comment: How long is the animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way -better than setTimeout- is use the [animation callback done](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks)

```
<mat-form-field [@error]="isError" 
                (@error.done)="isError = false"
                class="al-subscribe-form-field">
...
</mat-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `isError` to `false` after each animation cycle. If not the  transition `false <=> true` will never trigger since the `isError` is still `true`. Try the following

```js
public onSubscribeClick(): void {
  if (this.subscribeFormGroup.invalid) {
    this.isError = true;
    setTimeout(() => { this.isError = false }, 1000);    // <-- set the duration to the animation duration
  }
  ...
}
```